# Checkmark is critically ill

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

[image]

Comment: It's close enough, doesn't bug me unless there's a giant red line drawn down the middle of it.

Comment: @Undo It's close enough to its death. Please save it!!!

Comment: I think your point would be seen better if you used lines tangential to the three circles.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I just made an adjustment. This should be fixed on the next production server build.