# The checkmark isn't properly aligned with vote counts in the new beta sites

Tags: bug, design, beta-sites

Oh, [déjà vu](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250493/checkmark-is-critically-ill)?

The problem appears on the new beta theme too. Just noticed while cutting an image.

> [image]

And, just by the way: the check mark in the accepted state is aligned properly. Which makes the check mark shift a bit to the <s>right</s> ***left*** when I accept.

> [image]

---

How could I forget about the gif??

> [image]

Comment: What has been seen cannot be unseen. +1 (It's like that single-frame pause in the animation of loading cursor on Windows 7.)

Comment: "*Which makes the check mark shift a bit to the right when I accept.*" - NO, you mean to the **left**! (more than a year old, and I'm the first to notice this?!)

Comment: @rand Oh no!!!!!!! :D

Comment: @randal'thor: There is no bug so old it cannot still exist.

Comment: @NathanO'TᴇstingTuggy, once a bug gets old enough, it becomes a feature.